# The css code for underline does not work, and the css code doesnt work with the html part

Tags: html, css, sass

I am new to html and css, I just desined sample website on xd adobe. image of it is attached. The html works but when I am working on the css part, its is not working, It does not show on the website. I am coding at a scss file and not css file. I will appreciate any help! You can see I wrote on the css file that the logo should be without underLine but still its not working

```
        @import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@400;700&display=swap");
        body {
          background: #F2F2F2;
          font-family: 'Poppins';
          margin: 0;
        }
    
        .navbar {
          background: white;
          padding: 1em;
          .logo2 {
            text-decoration: none;
            font-weight: bold;
            color: black;
            font-size: 10em;
          }
        }
    
        .container {
          display: flex;
        }
```

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">

    <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
      <title>JustFly</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
    </head>

    <body>
      <div class="navbar">
        <div class="container">
          <a class="logo2" href="#">JustFly</a>
          <img id="mobile-cta" class="mobile-menu" src="images/menu.svg" alt="Hamburger Menu">

          <nav>
            <img id="mobile-exit" class="mobile-menu-exit" src="images/exit.svg" alt="Hamburger Menu">

            <ul class="primary-nav">
              <li class="current"> <a href="#">Home</a> </li>
              <li> <a href="#">FAQ</a> </li>
              <li> <a href="#">Pricing</a> </li>
            </ul>

            <ul class="secondary-nav">
              <li> <a href="#">Contact</a> </li>
              <li class="GoPremiumBtn"><a href="#">Buy Now</a> </li>
            </ul>
          </nav>
        </div>
      </div>

      <section class="hero">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="col">
            <h1 class="head">Fly Like Never Before.</h1>
          </div>
          <img id="mainImage" class="mainImage" src="images/icons8-fighter-jet-96.png" alt="Fighet Plane Image">

        </div>


      </section>
    </body>

    </html>
```

```
[Code][1]
[Output][2]
[Design][3]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/K19ny.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iluoa.png
  [3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fGDMf.png
```

Comment: its fine. i think there is a problem with your path. recheck the path of css file

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks fine and could also be tested successfully. The only thing which may cause your problem is your path to the CSS file.

Check if the path in `<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">` is correct.

Answer (score 0):

You said you are using scss for writing styles so you must be using local node setup or might be using the ruby compass thing.

Please check if your local development setup is outputting the css file at correct path.

you should try below command if using node-sass

```
sass --watch scss/main.scss:/css/main.css
```

Then add this to your HTML

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/main.css">
```